# Query to update 2 models same time c#

Tags: c#

Below are two sections of code.

Save course description

```
public int SaveCourseDescription(CourseDescription coursedescription, bool isEdit = false)
{
    string insertSql = @"INSERT INTO CourseDescription (CourseName, CourseCategoryID, CourseCountryID, CourseDuration)
    VALUES(@CourseName, @CourseCategoryID, @CourseCountryID, @CourseDuration);select last_insert_rowid()";
    string updateSql = @"update CourseDescription set CourseName = @CourseName, CourseCategoryID=@CourseCategoryID, CourseCountryID=@CourseCountryID, 
    CourseDuration=@CourseDuration where CourseID = @CourseID;select 
    last_insert_rowid()";
    string sql = isEdit ? updateSql : insertSql;
    int CourseDescriptionID;
    using (IDbConnection con = Functions.Connection)
    {
        con.Open();
        CourseDescriptionID = con.Query<int>(sql, coursedescription).FirstOrDefault();
    }
    return CourseDescriptionID;
}
```

and button save click

```
private void BtnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (TxtDescription.Text == "")
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Course Description cannot be empty!", "Error Saving", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        return;
    }
    if (_isEditing)
    {
        CourseDescription checkEditCourseDescription = new CourseDescription()
        {
            CourseName = TxtDescription.Text,
            CourseCategoryID = Convert.ToInt32(CmbCategory.Tag),
            CourseCountryID = Convert.ToInt32(CmbCountry.Tag),
            CourseDuration = Convert.ToInt32(TxtCourseDuration.Text),
            CourseID = Convert.ToInt32(lblDescriptionID.Text),
            CountryName = CmbCountry.Text,
            CourseCategoryName = CmbCategory.Text
        };
        if (CourseDescriptionComparer(_editCourseDescription, checkEditCourseDescription))
        {
            _dbcoursedescription.SaveCourseDescription(checkEditCourseDescription, true);
            _coursesDescription.ElementAt(_selectedRow).CourseName = checkEditCourseDescription.CourseName;
            _coursesDescription.ElementAt(_selectedRow).CourseCategoryName = checkEditCourseDescription.CourseCategoryName;
            _coursesDescription.ElementAt(_selectedRow).CourseCategoryID = checkEditCourseDescription.CourseCategoryID;
            _coursesDescription.ElementAt(_selectedRow).CourseCountryID = checkEditCourseDescription.CourseCountryID;
            _coursesDescription.ElementAt(_selectedRow).CountryName = checkEditCourseDescription.CountryName;
            _coursesDescription.ElementAt(_selectedRow).CourseDuration = checkEditCourseDescription.CourseDuration;
        }
        _editCourseDescription = null;
        _isEditing = false;
    }
    else
    {
        CourseDescription courseDescription = new CourseDescription()
        {
            CourseName = TxtDescription.Text,
            CourseCategoryID = Convert.ToInt32(CmbCategory.Tag),
            CourseCountryID = Convert.ToInt32(CmbCountry.Tag),
            CourseDuration = Convert.ToInt32(TxtCourseDuration.Text),
            CountryName = CmbCountry.Text,
            CourseCategoryName = CmbCategory.Text
        };
        courseDescription.CourseID = _dbcoursedescription.SaveCourseDescription(courseDescription);
        lblDescriptionID.Text = courseDescription.CourseID.ToString();
        _coursesDescription.Add(courseDescription);
        _selectedRow = _coursesDescription.Count - 1;
    }
    RefreshData();
    EnableButtons(true);
    ReadOnlyDataEntry(true);
}
```

This code updates CourseCategoryID in CourseDescription model on button save click. I have another model (Course), which contains also CourseCategoryID. I want to update it also in the same time. Any idea how and where to write it?

Comment: You can put two Inserts into a single Command Text Statement (your insertSql).  See msdn example : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/insert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15. Make sure you put the semicolon and Go into the statement.

Comment: After editing and on save click, I want to update CourseCategoryID in both models.
So i think I should use updateSql not insertSql. But how should I write it and in which section?

Comment: ExecuteNonQuery returns a integer which indicates the number of row changed.  Insert only works if the primary key does not exist.  If it exists ExecuteNonQuery return zero saying it was not successful.  Then you would have to use Update.  Update only works if the primary key does not exist and returns zero.  Then you have to use Insert.  So you need both Insert and Updated.  You try either on first and if you get zero then you try the other.

Comment: I didn't get you, this is what I already did. Can you show me what you mean using my example?

Comment: I was responding to your comment : "So i think I should use updateSql not insertSql".

Comment: I'm already checking in my code if I need to use update or insert.
"string sql = isEdit ? updateSql : insertSql;"
My question is I want to update CourseCategoryID in 2 different models having the same CourseCategoryID